# C++ Reading data into an array of structs generates error from OS SIGSEV

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, ifstream

I'm trying to read data from a .csv (therefore necessitating getline as far as I know).  I can't even begin to figure out what I've done wrong here.

My first function is supposed to open the file and pull the data into an array, positionsArray[].  However, as soon as I hit "positionsArray[i].agency = " when debugging, I get an error: The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system SIGSEGV.  I have no idea what's causing this other than maybe I don't have the array created or referenced properly.

```
void getData(std::ifstream& positionsListStream, Position positionsArray[], int streamSize) {
    std::string paredEntry, lineTemp, positionsList;
    std::string agency, classification, fullTime;
    std::string::size_type index = 0;
    double salary;
    for(int i = 0; i < streamSize; i ++) {
        getline(positionsListStream, lineTemp);
        index = lineTemp.find(",");
        agency = lineTemp.substr(0, index);
        lineTemp.erase(0, (index + 1));
        index = lineTemp.find(",");
        classification = lineTemp.substr(0, index);
        lineTemp.erase(0, (index + 1));
        index = lineTemp.find(",");
        fullTime = lineTemp.substr(0, index);
        lineTemp.erase(0, (index + 1));
        salary = salaryToDouble(lineTemp);
        positionsArray[i].agency = agency;
        positionsArray[i].classification = classification;
        positionsArray[i].fullTime = fullTime;
        positionsArray[i].salary = salary;
    }
    return;
}
```

main calls this function with

```
    getData(positionsListStream, &positionsArray[streamSize], streamSize);
```

Comment: What are you passing in for `positionsArray` and why aren't you using a `std::vector<Position>`?

Comment: The idea is to reference a previously initialized positionsArray in main.  Not sure I'm doing that correctly.

the entry in main looks like 
    Position positionsArray[streamSize];
    getData(positionsListStream, &positionsArray[streamSize], streamSize);

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72458655/edit) with the call to `getData`, then.

Comment: Updated question with line from main

Comment: And the definition of `positionsArray` and `streamSize` ? In general, having array parameters in a function is a code smell. It is more idiomatic to pass iterators, references to containers, or pointers.

Comment: `streamSize` is a constant of `int 1561`, and `positionsArray` is an array of structs called Position with three string parameters and one double.

Comment: Okay. But how much memory was allocated for `positionsArray`? (show the definition) And where do you think `&positionsArray[streamSize]` points to in that array?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `std::vector<Position>` and forget about memory management:

```
std::vector<Position> getData(std::ifstream& positionsListStream, int streamSize) {
    std::vector<Position> positionsArray;
    std::string agency, classification, fullTime;
    double salary;
    for(int i = 0; i < streamSize; i ++) {
        Position p;
        std::string::size_type index = 0;
                std::string lineTemp;

        getline(positionsListStream, lineTemp);
        index = lineTemp.find(",");
        p.agency = lineTemp.substr(0, index);

        lineTemp.erase(0, (index + 1));
        index = lineTemp.find(",");
        p.classification = lineTemp.substr(0, index);

        lineTemp.erase(0, (index + 1));
        index = lineTemp.find(",");
        p.fullTime = lineTemp.substr(0, index);

        lineTemp.erase(0, (index + 1));
        p.salary = salaryToDouble(lineTemp);

        positionsArray.push_back(p);
    }
    return positionsArray;
}
```

Comment: What do I do with my main to get those values to store into positionsArray?

Comment: `auto positionsArray = getData(positionsListStream, streamSize);`